# why does it go to the else statement when it's a draw?

Tags: python, string, compare

```py
steen = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

papier = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

schaar = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

import random

list = [steen,papier,schaar]

user = input ("Wat kies je? schaar, steen of papier? ")

if user == 'steen':
  print ('') 
  print ('Jij koos: ')
  print (steen)
  print ('')

elif user== 'schaar':
  print ('') 
  print ('Jij koos: ')
  print (schaar)
  print ('')  

elif user == 'papier':
  print ('') 
  print ('Jij koos: ')
  print (papier)
  print ('')  

else :

  print ("verkeerde ingave")

print ('de computer koos:')

computer = random.choice(list)

print (computer)

***if user == computer:
  print ('gelijk!!')***

if user == 'steen' and computer == schaar  :

  print ('Jij wint')

else :

  if user == 'schaar' and computer == papier:

    print ('Jij wint')

  else:

    if user == 'papier' and computer == steen:

      print ('Jij wint')

    else:

      print ('jij verliest\n')
```

Comment: the variable `user` is string the user typed. The variable `computer` contains one of the hands string. So they will never match. *btw, nice ascii art :)*

Comment: In answer to the headline question: As noted you don't properly assess a draw, comparing incompatible items, but ***even if you did***, you don't close off the rest of the code from execution, by using `elif` for tests after the draw option is tested. See my answer for a re-working of the problem, including a compact way of choosing the winner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT use `list` as a variable name. If you keep the list of choices (which I'll call `choices`) as strings, it's easier to validate the user entry, and then using the position in that list it's easy to compare the user and computer choices.

Following the graphic setup, you could have:

```py
choices = ('steen','papier','schaar')
graphix = ( steen, papier, schaar )
n_choices = len(choices)

user = input ("Wat kies je? schaar, steen of papier? ")

if user not in choices: # tests against all valid options
    print ("verkeerde ingave ", choices)

else :
    user_ix = choices.index(user) # use position
    print ('') 
    print ('Jij koos: ')
    print ( graphix[user_ix] ) 
    print ('')

    computer_ix = random.randrange(n_choices)
    print ('de computer koos:')
    print ( graphix[computer_ix] )

    if user_ix == computer_ix:
        print ('gelijk!!')

    elif (user_ix + 1)%n_choices == computer_ix:
        # modular arithmetic comparison for interest
        ## you lose to the next in (circular) list
        print ('Jij verliest \n')
    else:
        print ('Jij wint \n')
```

This also improves input error handling, but further improvement is certainly desirable, for example to allow the user a few tries to make a valid entry.